# Excel 2010 formatting - Conditiional formatting for dates

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a decent sized spreadsheet that lists various information about different products, including their prices.

Recently, I added a column that is labeled "Price last updated". I've been manually entering dates in this column and using the 3-color Conditional formatting tool to show older dates as Red and recent dates as Green.

I am doing this so I can visually look at the sheet and see which prices should be re-checked and updated. I'm realizing now that while my original idea is sound, it's only going to apply the formatting to the dates I've already entered (as is it's function).

What I'd really like to accomplish is to have the "Highest Value" auto-update to whatever "today's date" is so I can actually see over time which cells are getting older and should be updated.

Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get today's date into any formula using:

```
=TODAY()
```

So you could update your formula for your conditional formatting to reference that as the date check with what ever age you want. 
If you want it to have a check for anything older than say 30 days have a cell with:

```
=TODAY()-30
```

Then do a conditional formatting using "Highlight Cells Less Than" and select that cell with formula to get a date as the test.

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I'm looking for! I'll check up on it over the next few days as it updates.

Comment: Glad to hear it!